# NullPointerException @FindBy in PageObjectModel using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, findby

I am trying to implement PageObjectModel in Selenium. But I am getting NullPointer Exception at @FindBy. I hope someone can help me to identify my mistake. I created my Base class which sets config.properties file(it contains url,driver parameters) as well sets up driver. HomePage has object repository as well as actions and PageFactory is initialized. HomePageTest has all the tests. When I run the code, website is launched successfully. First test executes successfully. But at the second test it fails at FindBy.

Here is my code for reference.

Following is my Base class:

```
package com.seleniumEasy.qa.base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import com.seleniumEasy.qa.commonUtility.*;

public class Base {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setBaseline()
    {
        try {
            setProperties("\\Devp\\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\\src\\main\\java\\com\\seleniumEasy\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

        //setProperties("\\Devp\\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\\src\\main\\java\\com\\seleniumEasy\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
        setDriver();
    }
    /*@AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }*/
    
    public static void setProperties(String sFilePath) throws IOException
    {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(sFilePath);
        prop.load(fip);
    }
    
    public static void setDriver()
    {
        switch(prop.getProperty("browser").toLowerCase())
        {
            case "chrome":
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("chromekey"),prop.getProperty("chromedriverpath"));
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case "firefox":
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("firefoxkey"), prop.getProperty("firefoxdriverpath"));
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case "ie":
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("iekey"),prop.getProperty("iedriverpath"));
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case "edge":
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("edgekey"), prop.getProperty("edgedriverpath"));
                driver = new EdgeDriver();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Driver does not exists: "+ prop.getProperty("browser"));
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(commonUtil.Implicit_Wait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(commonUtil.PageLoad_Wait,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        if(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("No, thanks!")).isDisplayed())
            driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("No, thanks!")).click();
    
    }
}
```

Following is my Page file

```
package com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.seleniumEasy.qa.base.Base;

public class HomePage extends Base {
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"navbar-brand-centered\"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")
    WebElement InputForm;
    
    @FindBy(css="#navbar-brand-centered > ul:nth-child(1) > li.dropdown.open")
    List<WebElement> InputFormLst;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:first-of-type")
    WebElement simpleFormDemo;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(2)")
    WebElement checkBoxDemo;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(3)")
    WebElement radioBtnDemo;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(4)")
    WebElement dropDownLstDemo;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(5)")
    WebElement inputFrmSubmit;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(6)")
    WebElement ajaxForm;
    
    @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(6)")
    WebElement jQuerySelect;
    
    List<WebElement> inputFormList = new ArrayList();
    
            
    public HomePage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);     
    }
    
    public String validateTitle()
    {
        return driver.getTitle();
    }
    public SimpleForm validateSimpleFormDemo()
    {
        InputForm.click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.navbar-collapse.collapse.in>ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>a")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navbar-brand-centered\"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
        simpleFormDemo.click();
        return new SimpleForm();
    }
    
}
```

Following is my Test Page

```
package com.seleniumEasy.qa.Test;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import com.seleniumEasy.qa.base.Base;
import com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages.SimpleForm;

public class HomePageTest extends Base {

    HomePage homePage;
    SoftAssert softAssert;
    public HomePageTest()
    {
        homePage = new HomePage();
        softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    }
    
    
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void validateLoginPage()
    {
        String sTitle = homePage.validateTitle();
        softAssert.assertEquals(sTitle, "Selenium Easy Demo");
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void validateSimpleForm()
    {
        SimpleForm simpleForm = homePage.validateSimpleFormDemo();
        
    }
    
}
```

And here is the stacktrace

```
 Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 32000
Only local connections are allowed.
[1599758981.703][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Sep 10, 2020 10:59:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED: validateSimpleForm
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages.HomePage.validateSimpleFormDemo(HomePage.java:66)
    at com.seleniumEasy.qa.Test.HomePageTest.validateSimpleForm(HomePageTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@42d3bd8b: 8 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\Default suite exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 9 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\Default test.properties
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\index.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\main.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\groups.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\reporter-output.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\methods-not-run.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old\index.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\old exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6cd8737: 41 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@6aaa5eb0: 46 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\junitreports\TEST-com.seleniumEasy.qa.Test.HomePageTest.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Arundhati\Devp\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\test-output\junitreports exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3b81a1bc: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@6b2fad11: 12 ms
```

Here is the eclipse view

[image: EclipseView]

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 32000
Only local connections are allowed.
[1599758981.703][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Sep 10, 2020 10:59:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=85.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v85.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 85**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v85.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u252](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 85.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v85.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I incorporated all your suggestions. But still the same problem persist.  I still get NullPointerException

Comment: If I use driver.findElement() then the code works perfectly fine. So clearly the problem is with PageFactory and @FindBy which I am using. Following code worked

Comment: public SimpleForm validateSimpleFormDemo()
{
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navbar-brand-centered\"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
  //InputForm.click();
  simpleFormDemo.click();
  return new SimpleForm();
 }

Comment: can anyone please help to resolve this? I am still stuck.

Comment: Can anyone please help me to resolve this? I am still stuck on this.

Comment: If I use driver.findElement() for the same locator it is working but for @FindBy its giving NullPointerException. How is it possible? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to my own problem. NullPointerException is thrown when the driver object is null when the PageFactory is initialized.
The problem was before initializing the driver object I was calling PageFactory Initialization method. Thats why at the HomePage.java page in the constructor, driver was null.
Here is the updated code.
This is my Base class. I am initializing the cofig.properties file through the Base class constructor.

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.seleniumEasy.qa.base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import com.seleniumEasy.qa.commonUtility.*;

public class Base {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    
    
    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }
    public Base()
    {
        try 
        {
            setProperties("\\Arundhati\\Devp\\SeleniumEasy_Maven_POM_DataDrivenProject\\src\\main\\java\\com\\seleniumEasy\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    /*@AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }*/
    
    public static void setProperties(String sFilePath) throws IOException
    {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(sFilePath);
        prop.load(fip);
    }
    
    public static void setDriver()
    {
        
        if(prop.getProperty("browser").toLowerCase().equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("chromekey"),prop.getProperty("chromedriverpath"));
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(prop.getProperty("browser").toLowerCase().equals("firefox"))
        {
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("firefoxkey"), prop.getProperty("firefoxdriverpath"));
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(prop.getProperty("browser").toLowerCase().equals("ie"))
        {
            System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("iekey"),prop.getProperty("iedriverpath"));
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        else if(prop.getProperty("browser").toLowerCase().equals("edge"))
        {
            System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("edgekey"), prop.getProperty("edgedriverpath"));
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Driver does not exists: "+ prop.getProperty("browser"));
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(commonUtil.Implicit_Wait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(commonUtil.PageLoad_Wait,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        if(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("No, thanks!")).isDisplayed())
            driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("No, thanks!")).click();

            
    }
    
    public String getProperty(String key)
    {
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }
}

Following is code for my HomePage.java. No change in this file.

    /**
     * 
     */
    package com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    
    import com.seleniumEasy.qa.base.Base;
    
    public class HomePage extends Base {
        
        @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"navbar-brand-centered\"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")
        WebElement InputForm;
        
        @FindBy(css="#navbar-brand-centered > ul:nth-child(1) > li.dropdown.open")
        List<WebElement> InputFormLst;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:first-of-type")
        WebElement simpleFormDemo;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(2)")
        WebElement checkBoxDemo;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(3)")
        WebElement radioBtnDemo;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(4)")
        WebElement dropDownLstDemo;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(5)")
        WebElement inputFrmSubmit;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(6)")
        WebElement ajaxForm;
        
        @FindBy(css="ul.nav.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(6)")
        WebElement jQuerySelect;
        
        //List<WebElement> inputFormList = new ArrayList();
        
        
        public HomePage()
        {       
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);     
        }
        
        public String validateTitle()
        {
            return driver.getTitle();
        }
        public SimpleForm validateSimpleFormDemo()
        {
            
            InputForm.click();
            simpleFormDemo.click();
            return new SimpleForm();
        }
        
    }

Here is my HomePageTest file. I am calling the driver setup method following by creating the HomePage object in the BeforeClass annotation. No constructor in this class.

//package com.seleniumEasy.qa.testdata;
package com.seleniumEasy.qa.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import com.seleniumEasy.qa.base.Base;
import com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.seleniumEasy.qa.pages.SimpleForm;

public class HomePageTest extends Base {

    
    HomePage homePage;
    SoftAssert softAssert;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp()
    {
        setDriver();
        homePage = new HomePage();
        //PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class); 
        softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        
    }
    /*@AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }*/
    @Test(priority='b')
    public void validateLoginPage()
    {
        String sTitle = homePage.validateTitle();
        softAssert.assertEquals(sTitle, "Selenium Easy Demo");
    }
    
    @Test(priority='a')
    public void validateSimpleForm()
    {
        SimpleForm simpleForm = homePage.validateSimpleFormDemo();
    }
    
}
```